# Worktree parameter suddenly gets added when cloning repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-worktree

Ah the joys of setting up a new machine :/

I use the same VSCode on two different machines, I synced all the settings and extensions, they're both Windows 10 and running the same versions of VSCode.

On old one, when I clone the repo, I can move the repo's files and change the name of the folder and it'll work fine.

For some reason when I clone it on the new machine, an additional parameter gets added to the `.gitconfig` file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    worktree = D:/CODE/name_of_project
```

I've never had a problem with it before and suddenly I can't figure out why it's being added. Before I never had to change any configs etc.

I'm cloning the exact same repo on the old machine and the `.gitconfig` is exactly the same only without the `worktree` line. Anyone?

Comment: This issue has been driving me nuts for days too. It's clearly from VS code git extension: if I manually clone from the command line using `git clone` it's not there, only when cloning a repo directly from the VS code interface.

Comment: Ok, finally found a lead. Have you checked git for windows version on both machines? Looks like this is the problem: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2569

Comment: Filed an issue for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101244

Comment: Thanks mate. Glad I wasn't the only one who noticed! But it could be the git version because I didn't update it on the old machine

Comment: On my machine it seems to be the git version, I can confirm it doesn't happen on GfW 2.19.1 and it shows up in 2.27.0